# TargetProcess 404 error after installation

Tags: installation, asp.net

I installed [TargetProcess](http://targetprocess.com/) on my laptop but when trying to open the corresponding web page `http://localhost/TargetProcess2` I get 404 error.
I am running Win7 with IIS7 (7.5.7600.16385), MS SQL 2008 Express.

As suggested in Installation guide.pdf I have performed `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` (however in folder *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727* and not in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5.30729.1* because I simply don't have this folder although Ms Web Platform installer says that I have SP1 for NET Framework 3.5 installed)

**EDIT**: Actually no ASP.NET page is working. I tried creating a simple one with MS Visual Web Dev Express and published it to a new web-application on my localhost and I get the same 404...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh :) It turns out I had Appache installed as part of SVN installation and it was capturing requests to localhost. Interim solution was to change port for IIS pages.
There is a new problem though - browsers such as Chrome throw an

```
Error 312 (net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT)
```

error.
IE apparently ignores this error, so I can use the "TargetProcess" through IE...